# How do I create quintiles for a the income poverty ratio variable from HRS?

Tags: r, cut

I'm trying to create a quintile version of the income poverty ratio variable (continuous) in HRS (INPOVR). I keep getting the following error message: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `inc_pov_ratio = cut_number(INPOVR, n = 5)`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `cut_number()`:
! Insufficient data values to produce 5 bins.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I tried cut_number, cut_interval, and cut_width
Cut width runs but I'm not sure what the width would need to be to make quintiles.
data0_dsr %>% inc_pov_ratio_5cat = cut_width(INPOVR, width = 5)

Comment: Offer us `str(HRS$INPOVR)`

Comment: Do you want quintiles which are values that would allow cutting into equal size categories or do you want integers that would label which quintile they were in?

Comment: str(data0_drs$INPOVR)
 num [1:253398] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> summary(data0_drs$INPOVR)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   0.00    1.66    3.15    4.98    5.68 6035.23  138162

Comment: cutting into equal size categories

Comment: I don’t do tidyverse methods. You have NA’s in that vector. So this is a duplicate and the code would include: `quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.2), na.rm = TRUE,
         names = TRUE,  …)` (In base R)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it to work using the following code but the main thing is everything has to be done in base R: data$x <- factor(as.numeric(cut_number(data$INPOVR, n = 5)), levels= c(1:5),
                               labels = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5"))